# Dynamically add points to PointCloud without old data reload in WebGL

Tags: webgl, real-time, point-clouds

I would like to display point cloud data, which dynamically comes to PC station from a mobile lidar.

I want to process new points in order they come without touching already processed data. What ways i can do it in WebGL?

Comment: As i understand the question is really about updating your buffer with vertices data. With _gl.bufferSubData you could update part of buffer so your task is doable. I assume you can't know size of data which will come so i think it's reasonable to have several PointCloud geometries of fixed size adding new as soon as last one is filled.

Comment: Thanks, gl.bufferSubData  looks interesting. Im' going to investigate also three.js

Comment: In three.js mesh.add(childMesh) seems applicable. If you add data by chunks you can do it even without _gl.bufferSubData.